# Bootstrap responsive not responding in smartphones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem with [this website](http://arwink.com)

When I resize the browser window in my laptop the responsiveness works really well, but when I load the website in any smartphone it shows the desktop version.

I found this [similar problem](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/responsive-theme-not-responding-when-domain-forwarded) but there's no clear answer.

I also thought it was something about my code so I try with a bootstrap template, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are loading your page through an iframe. The page you linked is:

http://arwink.com/Test

But there is a full screen iframe on that page that loads:

http://www.bondzu.com/template/Test/

If you view the second link in a phone, you will see it resizes accordingly. But the first link does not. This is because the first link is missing the `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

If you add it to the first page, it *should* work, but I honestly have never tried to load a mobile page through an iframe on another mobile page before, so I can't speak from direct experience.

Comment: Indeed, he is missing the meta tag in his `<head>` for defining mobile devices.

Comment: It is, thats what I mention about the bootstrap template, you can have a look http://arwink.com/Test

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Wink - Augmented Reality</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/winky.png">
<meta name="description" content="Mobile apps to give animation and interactivity to your merchandise.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- MORE CSS-->`

Comment: Well, you forward it, meaning the `<head>` is from a different site. What happens is that it creates an `Iframe` in which the site is published, so technically, it shows you the empty site where it fetches your site. It won't read twice the `head`.